# Negotiations for terms of a post masters

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, masters

I recently got an offer to interview for a post masters program. This would be similar to a post doc in execution, however the program lasts 1 year. However, before that offer I accepted a position at a company I really wanted to work in, but have had delays in hiring.

I plan on working with this company and do not want to quit. However, would it be appropriate to attempt to negotiate or explain my situation during the in person interview they want me to attend?

I was hoping to maybe be able to do both programs, with the post masters done in a lesser capacity. Or should I notify them of my job and decline the interview?

Edit: this post masters program is similar to a post doc in that it is a paid program. The fellowship would provide a salary and health insurance for the year it lasted.

Comment: `before that offer I accepted a position at a company I really wanted to work in, but have had delays in hiring` - That statement contradicts itself. If you accepted a job offer then you've been hired.

Comment: @joeqwerty I think OP is talking about an offer for a university's master program, while having accepted a job offer recently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or should I notify them of my job and decline the interview?

I don't see why having a job prevents you from applying/interviewing for a Master's Program at some university.

This is an academic opportunity you have here, one that is independent to the fact that you have a job or not. Everybody has to make a living somehow, so *then* one can pursue other goals, like Master's Programs (which usually cost money ;)

Several people I know have at some point worked at the same time they were pursuing their Degrees. It requires discipline and effort, but it can be done.

That being said, I suggest you **attend to the interview, so you can know more about this Master's Program and gauge the time/effort it will require**. Only then you will have a clearer view on the feasibility of pursuing a Master's while working. Perhaps they even can present you with alternatives or suggest what steps you can take to make this work...

...but only if you attend you will know, so I say you go and then make your mind when you have a more complete and informed view of the situation and what it is about.

Comment: Sorry I didnt explain the post masters well. This is a paid program so i would be doing research in a field of study for about 1 year according to the fellowship. If I were to be accepted i would not pay anything.